# WPF - Datagrid selection changed with background worker

Tags: wpf, datagrid, backgroundworker

I am writing a program that reads information from a device through the serial port. I have a list of available devices in a datagrid. When the user clicks on a row, it fetches information from the device and displays it in a separate list. It usually takes about a second for the device to respond and the information to populate. However, during this second, the datagrid row does not highlight as selected. So it takes about a second from the time the mouse clicks on the datagrid row for it to actually show as highlighted/selected.

I thought a background worker thread would be the best thing to use for this, but I get the same results with the code below. Am I using it incorrectly, or is there something else I should be doing for selecting a datagrid row?

```
private void relayList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += GetLinks;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

 private void GetLinks(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
    //send message to viewModel and do time-consuming work here
}
```

Comment: Instead of reading within the SelectionChanged event, what about within the MouseUp event, with a condition of course to determine if reading should be started.

Comment: Are you sure the ~1 second delay represents the time spent waiting for the device, and not the time spent updating the UI in response?  Best to verify this before spending too much time here.  Also make sure you're not marshaling yourself back onto the `Dispatcher` from within the view model while you're doing your calculations.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was called away. Thanks for the responses; I will try both and update.

Comment: Did you give my answer below a try?

Comment: @DaleFrancis I really appreciate the answer, but I didn't quite understand it. I am reading back over it and trying it now.

Comment: Thanks again for the responses, everyone. @MikeG's suggestion of sending the request on MouseUp is working fine, but I obviously need to practice and learn a lot more about BackgroundWorker. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundWorker has a RunWorkerCompleted method. It will run in the execution context of the UI thread.

There is also a result property that is used to pass a result to the next method which is the RunWorkerCompleted method.

```
private void yourMethod()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += DoWorkMethod;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompletedMethod;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void RunWorkerCompletedMethod(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = (string)e.Result;

    // do stuff here
}

private void DoWorkMethod(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = string.Empty; // Your device data
}
```

If you desperatly want to not use the completed method. Do not use dispatcher, instead use SynchronizationContext.

You will need to store SynchronizationContext.Current on a field when you first run your form but after that you can invoke whatever you need on the UI thread.